# Which to use - recursive query or specific regex

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I have a CSV line, that looks like:

```
foo, bar, baz, "england, scotland, wales, ireland", sith
```

and need to convert it into

```
"foo", "bar", "baz", "england, scotland, wales, ireland", "sith"
```

I've decided to replace all commas between double quotes with 'comma', but after picking up a substirng between the double quotes I have a problem with regex to do so, because while using a

```
replace(/(.+)(,)(.+)/g, "'comma'")
```

I take next substring

```
"england, scotland, wales'comma' ireland"
```

instead of

```
"england'comma' scotland'comma' wales'comma' ireland"
```

I don't want to use regex with more complicated structure like

```
/(.+)(,)(.+)(,)(.+)(,)(.+)/g
```

and wish to group word with comma sign but can't pick a right regex for it, so I use a recursive substring search with match in for loop. Am I doing right, or there is a regex that fits but I haven't find it yet. Thank you.

Comment: don't use regex, use a [CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12785546/497418).

Comment: this is probably pushing the boundaries of being an opinionated question, but I'd also avoid regex in this case, as you will end up with something that's at best hard to read, at worst, a maintainability nightmare.

Comment: `replace(/(.+)(,)(.+)/g, "'comma'")` seems unclear. Why are you trying to replace with comma?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a split function that supports regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
var re = /"([^"]*)"|([^\s,][^,]*)/g;
var str = 'foo, bar, baz, "england, scotland, wales, ireland", sith';
var subst = '"$1$2"';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: oh, i forget this.. Why you used this `([^\s,][^,]*)` instead of `([^\s,]+)` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: it's only to ensure that the first character is not a white space and to trim a possible leading space (since there is a space after each  `,`).